# Why is DBA_SEGMENTS presenting twice the amount of data than the DBA_TABLES?

Tags: oracle, statistics, tablespaces

I tried to compute the audit log table usage using the following steps:

1. Truncate all the audit log table data (i.e. `AUD$`)
2. Perform test case that inserts and update data, also delete statement but it wont delete anything.
3. Measure the byte used on the dba segment.

   ```
   select tablespace_name,bytes from dba_segments
   where tablespace_name ='SYSTEM'
   and SEGMENT_NAME = 'AUD$';
   ```
4. Recompute of statistical data.
5. Retrieve the byte used in the statistical data.

   ```
   select NUM_ROWS * AVG_ROW_LEN as BYTE_USED
   from DBA_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'AUD$';
   ```

The value I get from #3 is more than twice that of #5, Why is it allocating too much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your select on `dba_tables` doesn't take into account:

- Empty blocks in the table (see `initial`/`next`, `minextents` and `freelist`-related storage parameters among others)
- Empty space in the blocks (due to `pct_free` mainly)
- Block headers (`initrans` influences this size, among others)

I.e. it doesn't take into account the physical storage of the data at all. `dba_segments` on the other hand only counts physical blocks for the segment, regardless of how much data they contain.

A table with a `pct_free` set to 50% and never updated will have statistically half-empty blocks for example, and the calculation you did on `dba_tables` will reveal that when compared to `dba_segments`.

See the [Logical Storage Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/cncpt/logical-storage-structures.html) docs to learn more about how data is stored in your database (and the overhead involved).